# Как с помощью VBS проверить доступность текстового файла на чтение?

Tags: windows-10, vbscript

Подскажите пожалуйста функцию на VBS которая проверяет файл на чтение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попытаться открыть файл на чтение и посмотреть что получится

```vbs
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fs, f
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error Resume Next ' Отключаем штатные исключения
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("1.csv", ForReading, False, TristateFalse)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
  f.Close
  WScript.Echo "OK"
Else
  WScript.Echo "Failed"
End If
On Error GoTo 0  ' Включаем исключения обратно
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Павел если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то отметьте его как верный